# Do I need multiple versions of Windows Visual C++ Redistributable installed?

Tags: windows-10, visual-c++

I stumbled upon the fact that I had about 8 different versions (I started uninstalling them) of `Windows Visual C++ Redistributable` installed.

1. I wonder, can I remove all except the latest one?
2. Why isn't Windows itself taking care of this?
3. I work a lot with Python. Is there a specific reason I'd need an older version?

Thanks!
Ronny

[image]